# NAudio generating error when played back again(2nd time and later)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, naudio

The first time I click the PLAY button, everything works fine, but the next time it generates the error in this line :

```
    waveOutDevice.Init(mainOutputStream);
```

Please see the screenshot for details of the error. Here below is the section of my code :

```
    private void Play()
    {
        string audioFile = "temp.mp3";
        try
        {
            if (mainOutputStream != null)
                mainOutputStream = null;
            mainOutputStream = CreateInputStream(audioFile);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
        if (mainOutputStream != null)
        {
            waveOutDevice.Init(mainOutputStream);
            waveOutDevice.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

The error code is : -2004287486

TargetSite is : *{Void ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)}*

All this is going over my head, so please help me point out the error site and with a little bit of explanation(if possible) and of course a work around for this situation. Thanks.

[image: Error Screenshot]

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the response.  Tried that as well, but still the same problem. The file gets played again, but that error message keeps appearing after some delay. Sometimes, the error-message appears few seconds after the entire application has been closed. And it appears a lot of times, one-after-another, probably once for every time  the file was played.

Answer (score 2):

The error code is 0x88890002 ([AUDCLNT_E_ALREADY_INITIALIZED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), which points to the old output device not being disposed properly. Make sure you Dispose of your waveOutDevice and create a new one for the next playback.